# Ionic 3 - Infinite scroll with Horizontal scroll

Tags: ionic3, ion-scroll, ion-infinite-scroll

I have used Infinite scroll with "Vertical Scroll" and it works as expected.

On a different page, I have multiple "Horizontal scrolls". I would like to make them infinite scrolls as well. I used the `<ion-infinite-scroll>` tag for the horizontal scroll, but it does not seem to work as required. I googled around as well but couldnt find much help.

I am pasting my code below.

`<ion-scroll scrollX="true">
    <ion-card *ngFor="let x of y">
        ...
    </ion-card>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event, y)">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-scroll>`

One thing I noticed is, when i scroll all the way to the bottom of the page, the `ionInfinite` method gets called on all the horizontal scrolls. So it looks like the vertical infinite scroll is getting triggered instead of the horizontal infinite scroll.

Please let me know if I am missing anything or if there is any specific way that the code needs to be written.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with Ionic, but you can do it by yourself:

**Template:**

```
<div (scroll)="YOURMETHOD($event)">
    //do something
</div>
```

**Page.ts:**

```
public YOURMETHOD(event:any){
    console.log(event)
}
```

**Ionic:**

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.1.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.5.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1
```